# syntax of ngx-translate string used in a title attribute dynamically with a parameter from an provided array

Tags: angular, primeng, string-interpolation, ngx-translate

I am trying to find the correct syntax for this to work:

```
<th *ngFor=" let col of columns" [class]="col.class || ''" pResizableColumn
[pSortableColumn]="col.field" pReorderableColumn
title="{{'sort.by.value'|translate:({value:col?.header}) }}">               
{{ col.header|translate }}
</th>
```

The columns are defined as:

```
export const defaultColumns = [
    {
        field: 'colour',
        type: 'string',
        header: 'Colour',
        filterMatchMode: 'contains'
    },
    {
        field: 'sample_template_id',
        type: 'number',
        header: 'Sample Type',
        filterMatchMode: 'equals',
    },
    {
        field: 'name',
        type: 'string',
        header: 'Name',
        filterMatchMode: 'contains'
    }
]
```

Part of my en-US.json translation file looks like this (as do the other languages):

```
"Colour": "Colour",
"Name": "Name",
"sort": {
        "by": {
            "a-z": "Sort: A-Z",
            "alerts": "Sort: ALERTS",
            "last-scanned": "Sort by last scanned",
            "type": "Sort: TYPE",
            "value": "Sort By {{value}}",
            "z-a": "Sort: Z-A"
        },
        "title": "Sort"
    },
"Sample Type": "Sample Type",
```

The part in question is the title attribute:

What I tried:

1. `title="{{'sort.by.value'|translate:({value:col?.header}) }}"`

Result: Using interpolation in this title attribute throws an NG5002 error: `error NG5002: Parser Error: Unexpected token {, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 2 in [{{'sort.by.value'|translate:({value:col?.header}) }}]`

2. `title="{{'sort.by.value'|translate:{value:col?.header} }}"` (removing the () parentheses)

Result: Using interpolation in this title attribute throws an NG5002 error: `error NG5002: Parser Error: Unexpected token {, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column 2 in [{{'sort.by.value'|translate:({value:col?.header}) }}]`

3. `title="'sort.by.value'|translate:{value:col?.header}"` (removing the interpolation)

Result: no error thrown, but also doesn't replace the string. Shows `'sort.by.value'|translate:{value:col?.header}` in the HTML

4. `title="'sort.by.value'|translate:({value:col?.header})"` (removing the interpolation but keeping the () parentheses)

Result: no error thrown, but also doesn't replace the string. Shows `'sort.by.value'|translate:({value:col?.header})` in the HTML

5. `title="'sort.by.value'|translate:{value:'Name'}"` (removing parentheses, and replacing the dynamic col.header property with the string that is used)

Result: no error thrown, but also doesn't replace the string. Shows `'sort.by.value'|translate:({value:col?.header})` in the HTML

6. `title="{{'sort.by.value'|translate:{value:'Name'} }}"` (adding the string interpolation again, replacing the dynamic col.header property with the string that is used)

Result: Shows the correct string (Sort by Name) in the HTML, but is not dynamic.

What did I miss? None of the other questions and proposed answers worked unfortunately..

I should mention it's still Angular 11 but will be updated soon, and this project uses primeng v11.1 and ngx-translate v13.0

Comment: `title="'sort.by.value'|translate:{value:col?.header}` should be the correct one, make sure that col?.header is in fact a string. and not undefined.

Comment: not sure if you tried this, but this should work: `[title]="'sort.by.value'|translate:({value: (col?.header | translate)})"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question after trying for half of the last day:

this is the solution that I finally settled upon:

```
title="{{'sort.by.value'|translate}} {{col?.header | translate}}"
```

My problem was, I needed the `col?.header` translated as well and that just seemed to cumbersome to do with some translate parameters.

I just had to pay attention, to make sure the `title` attribute is not `[title]` otherwise this also worked, as weird as it looks:

```
[title]="(('sort.by.value'|translate) + ' ' + (col?.header | translate))"
```